# Grade Average using While or Until Loop

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2012, console-application

I am taking an online Visual Basic programming 1 course with very little instruction. I have spent hours on every assignment and can usually find help by looking things up and testing. I have not been able to find help for this (or I find it in another language and I don't know how to translate into VB console). I am asking the user to input test scores. My problem is I don't know how many scores that they will input. I need this number so that I can calculate an average and return a grade.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim testScore As Integer = 1
        Dim scoreSum As Integer = 0
        Dim numberOfScore As Integer
        Dim average As Integer

        Console.WriteLine("Enter all the test scores. When you are done enter 0. ")

        Do While (testScore <> 0)
            testScore = Console.ReadLine()
            scoreSum = scoreSum + testScore
            numberOfScore += testScore
            average = scoreSum / numberOfScore
            Console.Write(scoreSum.ToString)
        Loop

        Console.WriteLine("The average is " + (scoreSum / numberOfScore).ToString())

        If (average >= 90) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Your Grade is A ")

        ElseIf (average >= 80) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Your Grade is B ")

        ElseIf (average >= 70) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Your Grade is C ")

        ElseIf (average >= 60) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Your Grade is D ")

        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Your Grade is F. " & "You will have to repeat this course. ")

        End If

        Console.ReadLine()


    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment `numberOfScore` by 1 instead of by `testScore`.  Average would be the sum over number of scores.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Main()
Dim testScore As Integer = 1
Dim scoreSum As Integer = 0
Dim numberOfScore As Integer
Dim average As Integer

Console.WriteLine("Enter all the test scores. When you are done enter 0. ")

testScore = Console.ReadLine()

Do 
    scoreSum = scoreSum + testScore
    numberOfScore += 1
    average = scoreSum / numberOfScore
    Console.Write(scoreSum.ToString)
    testScore = Console.ReadLine()
Loop While (testScore <> 0)

Console.WriteLine("The average is " + (scoreSum / numberOfScore).ToString())

If (average >= 90) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Your Grade is A ")

ElseIf (average >= 80) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Your Grade is B ")

ElseIf (average >= 70) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Your Grade is C ")

ElseIf (average >= 60) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Your Grade is D ")

Else
    Console.WriteLine("Your Grade is F. " & "You will have to repeat this course. ")

End If

Console.ReadLine()


End Sub
```

Comment: @SB That was helpful, but there must be another error. I averaged 98, 3 times. It came back with the incorrect average, and gave me a grade of "C". Thank you!

Comment: That is because the code will count the zero as a score and instead divide the total by 4 which would probably get you a C grade. 98*3=294 is the total. 294/4= 73.5 average = "C".